# json file manipulation with javascript

Tags: json

I am getting json as response from server like below;

```
{"data":"<div align=\"left\"><select id =\"test\"><option id=\"1\" value=\"one\"><option id=\"2\" value=\"two\" selected></select></div>"};
```

I want to manipulate above json file using javascript to change option one to be selected instead of option two.

Any hints please.

Regards,

Raj

Answer (score 0):

Your life would be easier if your JSON was actually data represented as JSON, instead of serialized DOM fragments embedded in a JSON value, e.g.,

```
[
    {"value": "one"}
    , {"value": "two", "selected": true}
]
```

Then when you turn that into an object, you could just do something like this (assume for the sake of the example that you named the result `myArray`):

```
myArray[0].selected = true; // Select the first element
myArray[1].selected = false; // Deselect the other element; in many cases, you'd probably need some sort of loop.
```

Comment: Yes your right,but i am getting dom elements as response in my json.Any hints on this.

Comment: @raj If you don't control the server, I guess you're stuck with it. If you do control the server, you should be able to return whatever you want. Assuming you're stuck with serialized DOM elements, I'd suggest creating a DOM fragment from it, sticking that in a variable, using traditional DOM manipulation techniques, and then swapping its `innerHTML` for the `innerHTML` of whatever control is currently on screen.